# Why can't I call my JS function from the console?

Tags: javascript

I have a file called newoperation.js well loaded in the network tab of the developper tools of my web browser
And in my newoperation.js file there is a function defined like this:

```
function getUSDtoHTGRate ()  {
    //ICI 
    console.log(1)
    $.post('ajax.php?action=getUSDtoHTGrate&json=1', {}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

But why, when I type into the console `getUSDtoHTGRate()`, I have:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getUSDtoHTGRate is not defined

Comment: The function is not defined within the global context. It's most likely inside an IIFE or a module.

Comment: No, I put my function getUSDtoHTGRate () at the top of the file, not inside a function or other

Comment: How are you including the file on the page? Note that bundlers like Webpack might automatically attempt to isolate every file, so the build setup is probably also relevant.

Comment: The file is well included in my page with a script markup

Comment: Any errors in the console? Because if it uses literally this code, you should have a syntax error. You're missing a closing `)` for `$.post()`

Comment: To be sure it's not a scope problem you can define the function as "window.getUSDtoHTGRate = function()...". Although I read VLAZ comment now and probably that's it